XUbuntu Dummy Sound XPS 14 9440
I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my XPS 14 9440.
I have tried Ubuntu from latest to 14.04 LTS, nothing worked either a dirver is missing for wifi or Dummy Sound so It has no sound. Either keyboard doesnt work or Some error.
I have tried Fedora didnt Work, Kubuntu, Linux Mint as well now I am installing XUbuntu.
With this, it still saying Dummy output.
when I do this:
junaid-farooq@junaid-farooq-XPS-14-9440:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:277: no soundcards found...

I making some tweaks and I was able to make the result of above in PCH [HDA Intel PCH]


I tried almost every solution available but it didnt work. with some change I dont know which, I was able to populate the Configuration screen but then its gone again.
This is my audio details
junaid-farooq@junaid-farooq-XPS-14-9440:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Dell Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 240, IOMMU group 21
    Memory at 581d310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 581d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_mtl

This is my release details for XUbuntu
junaid-farooq@junaid-farooq-XPS-14-9440:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

Can anyone please help me? this is my very last chance to have ubuntu because I have tried every variant of it. Thank you

According to https://www.reddit.com/r/DellXPS/comments/1bsqq3b/linux_on_a_2024_xps_13_9340/ ths sound works on Ubuntu, have you checked it by running the USB of Xubuntu and Ubuntu and Trying and checking Audio?

I have tried with different Debian distros and after research seems like there is regression in drivers. Tried with manjaro, working well out of box without issues.
